# How are these characters produced?

Tags: c, loops, pointers

```
int main(void)
{
char s[] = "Hsjodi", *p;
for(p = s; *p; p++)
    --*p;
    puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

The output writes Grinch but I cant understand how this code executes. How can it write out Grinch when such letters `G`,`r`,`i` for example does not exist in  the `char` array and when does loop terminates our exactly does `*p` means?

Comment: `--*p` is decrementing the current character pointed by `p`, such that `H` turned to `G`, `s` to `r` and so on.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That doesn't explain where the G comes from.

Comment: Books that don't explain their examples are worthless.  Books that use ill-advised "tricky" or "clever" code are worse than worthless.  If the book uses the "random indent" style of your example, that should ring alarm-bells from the outset.  First, so no one else makes the mistake of buying this book, at least tell us the title and author, second relegate the book to propping up your monitor.  A quick search shows that this code was used in a University of Alabama course test paper - so I am wondering whether there really is a "book" of if you are just attempting to cheat on some homework?

Comment: @Rob I presume it is obvious that `'G'='H'-1`

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it was pointing at an ASCII table but p = s.

Comment: @Rob I afraid I don't understand your comments. `p` is pointing initially to a string containing "Hsjodi", so all of the data is taken from there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And G isn't in the array so where is G coming from?

Comment: @Rob `'G'` is an output of a calculation with input `'H'`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that `for` loop does not have any braces to create a block, so the loop body is only

```
--*p;
```

which is same as

```
--(*p);
```

Now, as per the above statement all the elements in the array, until the terminating `null`, has been reduced one place. That means, `H` is now `G`, `s` is now `r` and so on.<sup>NOTE</sup>

Also, the condition check in the loop `*p` is a short-hand form of writing `*p != '\0'` or `*p != 0`.

After the decrement through the loop, the modified array has been printed through `puts()`.

---

NOTE: You may want to check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference.

Comment: @Rob sorry, I did not understand. What is it?

Comment: @Rob p is pointing to s, which is an string containing the characters 'Hsjodi\0' So *p is initially the letter 'H'

Comment: @FredK Yes, and --(*p) points to what? I don't think p ever pointed to any ASCII table.

Comment: @Rob it is not about ASCII _table_, notice the initialization in the loop, `p = s`, that means, at the beginning, `p` points to the beginning of the array in `s` and we keep on incrementing the pointer until we reach the address which contains the null terminator, which has a decimal value `0`.

Comment: Now I can explain it (I'm on my phone at an airport where it's hard to think). This code is sequencing through each element of the array and decrementing its value by one. That value is equal to the character before it which, in this case, causes it to spell out 'Grinch'. Your mention of the ascii table is what confused me. I didn't notice the 'decrementing the character' part.

Comment: @Rob yes, that's it. I added the table just in case anyone is interested to know the relation between the ASCII values of the alphabets. :-)

Comment: Thanks it answered my question. But can't you rate my questions so that i can ask more question wasen't it good this question?